# Publish deleted items

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7

I'm facing some problems, somehow to provide to content authors solution/advice to delete huge sections of website translated (having language versions) and with references set on presentation or data items inside content tree.

Removing all items plus references raise another problem how to make the changes visible on web database. Publish cannot be used, even workflow is present changes are made on presentation (master instance is mapped to a preview site for client) on pages (by different agencies) and cannot reach live, only when they decide to. Used as well number of versions per language (limited to 6, rest removed) if all 6 variants are trapped in workflow publish will publish item with all fields empty, we don't want to have a blank page.

And there are other concerns regards incorrect work, sometimes agencies publish/submit incorrect/unproved content and they blame each other case someone publish accidental pages (presentation settings/datasource) so i want to pick the best strategy here not to give room for content authoring agency's to blame their incorrect work other then them.

I have few approaches to do it right but..

- do same deletion of items on web database via CMS in theory works (tested on locally in sitecore 7.2 - works) on Production CMS (Sitecore 7.0 - admin rights, no  access to server files for me) fails as in next image:
  [image]
- write a module (Sitecore command to remove all references and  removing/recycling web database item cannot be performed via code because it will trow same error as above)

**Question 1.** Why this error occurs at CMS item deletion if web database is selected (Sitecore 7.0)

2. Found in this deprecated [post](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/09/manage-publication-of-deletions-with-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx) something what seems to be the solution: Add publishing commands to the recycle bin. Well here I get a bit blocked, adding the publish command  on Recycle Bin ribbons, don't know if it's possible to do this (what I'm publishing I do not understand). I created something but it's not working:

[image]

This is the result :(

[image]

**Question 2.** Is publishing commands to the recycle bin possible? If yes please help me with a documentation to implement it and understated what/how is published.

If you have other suggestions (beside publish item + sub items or publish website) please help me out.

Thank You.

Comment: Can't you just unpublish the sections in question that need to go away? http://firebreaksice.com/unpublish-sitecore-content/

Comment: Hi Mark, not knowing about this functionality, I will give it a shot on monday I will test it and came back with the result, thank you.

Comment: For question 1, I think you made an upgrade for Sitecore recently, but you forgot to run Sql Upgrade scripts on Web database, 
As for the second question, i don't quite understand what are you trying to do

Comment: @MarkUrsino tested, nice feature, not exactly what I need. I decided to let Items (Pages) having null references to deleted/unpublished on Web because in all user controls checks if Item != null and haslanguageversion() resolving null items. About publish: Content Authors will publish Items pages at some point from master where references has been deleted when  Item was removed with option to remove all sc links.